# Custom RazorPage get access to IRequest and Route Info

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

Using the Razor implementation for ServiceStack and AspNetCore how can I get access to the IRequest to get the route info for a custom razor page?  Ultimately I want to get to the Name attribute on the route if possible.

public abstract class CustomView : RazorPage
    {
        public IRequest Req { get; set; }  // always null

```
    protected Breadcrumb Breadcrumb
    {
        get
        {
            return new Breadcrumb(this.Req); // need to pass IRequest to breadcrumbs so it can produce them
        }
    }
}
```

Routes are defined with a custom attribute which inherits from Route.

```
[CustomRoute("/message/{id}", View = "MessageDetailView", Name = "GetById")]
```

Custom Route:

```
 public class CustomRoute : RouteAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
        public CustomRoute(string path) : base(path) { }
        public CustomRoute(string path, string verbs) : base(path, verbs) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at least in web applications (as opposed to self hosted) the following works:

```
 IRequest req = HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest();
```